# FIREDAC-UTF8 encoding is not supported when reading FTS table

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe3, firedac

When in DELPHI XE3 with Firedac we create a table table0 and insert text in UTF8  encoding all is OK.

```
CREATE TABLE table0 (mytext Ntext,publishdate date);
INSERT INTO table0 (mytext,publishdate) VALUES ('привет','1998-12-07');
```

But, when we create a FTS table and insert text in UTF8.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE table1 USING FTS4(mytext,publishdate);
INSERT INTO table1 (mytext,publishdate) VALUES ('привет','1998-12-07');
```

and read the data with

```
SELECT mytext FROM table1
```

we get "??????".

The same commands in SQLITE Expert Personal return "привет". It means that in the table after Insert command we have 'привет' and select returns the data not in UTF8  encoding.

What may be done to get from the table correct value with Firedac

```
ADQuery.Open('SELECT mytext FROM table1')?
```

Comment: So here `AsWideString`, or `AsWideMemo` returns question marks? Or what do you use to get values? Also, for inserting you should use parameters with the similar access.

Comment: for future readers try set `StringFormat=Unicode` in the connection string, this will make firedac treat all string types as Unicode strings, in the time of writing this is not the default

Answer (score 0):

I think it is FireDac bug.

I've changed the following lines in ADSQLiteTypeName2ADDataType procedure of uADPhysSQLite.pas unit

```
SetLen(AOptions.FormatOptions.MaxStringSize, False);
AType := dtAnsiString;
```

to

```
SetLen(AOptions.FormatOptions.MaxStringSize, True);
AType := dtWideString;
```

for the case ABaseTypeName = 'VARCHAR'

and

```
SELECT mytext FROM table0
```

returns the correct value at runtime. But at design time still we have '??????'.

But I don't think it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should directly set parameter type as AsWideString:

```
Query.SQL.Text:='INSERT INTO table1 (mytext, publishdate) VALUES (:mytext,: publishdate);';
Query.Params[0].AsWideString := mytext;
Query.Params[1].AsDate := publishdate;
Query.ExecSQL;
```

Reference: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Unicode_Support_(FireDAC)#Parameter_Values